# Restaining a deck after scraping, prime with oil base?

Tags: deck

We have scraped and washed our large older pressure treated deck which had originally had an oil based semi transparent stain, but now has a latex solid stain. We have always followed our paint stores advice to stain the scraped areas with an oil based primer and then do entire deck with solid acrylic stain (both Cabot). Is this still the best? I have some primer and lots of the solid stain.